# Creating custom detail page tab same as normal standard detail page with two sections with different fields using LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components

I have to built custom record detail page ,same as standard like having inline editing with pencil icon and save functionality as standard has using LWC .
I tried this HTML

```
<template>
<div class="acc-container">
    <lightning-accordion class="example-accordion" allow-multiple-sections-open
onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}
active-section-name={activeSections}>
<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update">
</lightning-button>
    <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Teaching">
<lightning-record-form
    record-id={recordId}
    object-api-name="Opportunity"
    fields={teacherFields} ">
</lightning-record-form>
</lightning-accordion-section>
```

and output ID got like each section have filed all are coming in editing mode , I dont want save edit and cancel button for each form fields, Just wanted to handel all inline editing with Single button save, Not able to acheive this

Can anyone help me on this urgent basis.
[image]